# JWPlayer 6 error message "Error loading stream: ID not found on server"

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, wowza, jwplayer6, flash-video

I am using JWPlayer to connect to Wowza Media Server. I am using RTML url to connect. When I make a video request I can see video playing very clearly and good quality of video as well. But sometimes I get "Error loading stream: ID not found on server" message. 80% of video request are successfull but 20% video request show this error message. I am connecting to Wowza Media Server. I contacted JWplayer support team but they replied by saying that it could be wowza server side. I checked the wowza logs and I am getting the NetConnection Fail message sometimes but logs also show that client is disconnecting.

JW player javascript code is as follows:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
       'file': url,
       'flashplayer': 'jwplayer.flash.swf',
       'provider': 'rtmp',
       rtmp: {
        'bufferlength': 5
       },
       'primary': "flash",
       'wmode': 'opaque',
       'autostart': 'true',
       'allowfullscreen': 'true',
       'controlbar': "none",
       'controlbar.idlehide': 'true',
       'logo.hide': 'true',
       'image': imageurl,
       'stretching': 'exactfit',
       'height': '500px',
       'width': '500px'
    });

    jwplayer("myElement").onError(function(event){
                setTimeout(function ()
                {
                     jwplayer("myElement").load([{'file':url}]);
                },5000); 
       }
    );
```

I ran wireshark on my windows machine and can see following error message NetConnection.connect.Rejected. The client is disconnecting and trying to reconnect again but is not able to connect and shows error message "Error loading stream: ID not found on server".

It is JW Player because when I click on start video the JW player shows buffering icon visible on display and it does not show video but just shows buffering icon at this time if I maximise the video the video is shown playing immediately. I also managed to find some links similar to my error message for JWPlayer 6 but they are using secure token but I am not doing any authentication on wowza side so I dont need to worry about it. The links are as follows:

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/6062365-jwplayer-6-and-private-rtmp-streaming-from-cloudfront
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=437093#437093

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're using a number of attributes that simply don't exist in JW Player 6, and you're using illegal values for some of the others (like 500px for dimensions, instead of just 500). If you don't see something in the configuration guide, you can't use it! And get rid of the timeout function until you've got things working properly.

Comment: Do you have a link as well?